# foreign key in django-import-export

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

First of all pardon me for my poor English. I'm using django-import-export to upload excel file into my **student model** that has foreign key relationship with **university model**

`student.. models.py`:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    institution = models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    age = models.IntegerField()
    faculty = models.CharField( max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    program = models.CharField( max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

`university.. models.py`:

```
class University(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    phone_no1 = PhoneNumberField()
    phone_no2 = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    fax_no = PhoneNumberField()
    website = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    pob = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="logos/", blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

After reading  django-import-export documentation about **ForeignKeyWidget**
I edited my **resources.py** file as following and it works fine when I upload excel file that contain **institution id** and other **student information**

`resources.py`

```
class StudentResource(resources.ModelResource):
    institution = fields.Field(
        column_name='institution',
        attribute ='institution',
        widget = ForeignKeyWidget(University, 'id')
        
    )
    class Meta:
        model=Student
```

But I don't want to include **institution id** into my excel file while I am uploading, because I can find the **institution id** from *Registrar Staff*  logged in since the **RegistrarStaff model** has foreign key relationship with **university model**

```
class RegistrarStaff(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE, primary_key = True)
    university = models.ForeignKey(University, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
       return str(self.user)
```

This is the way I able to find  **institution id** based on whose university *Registrar Staff* is logged in and passed the value into resource like on number 4 in **views.py**

`views.py`:

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        loged=request.user.id
        univ = RegistrarStaff.objects.get(pk=loged).university_id
        student_resource = StudentResource(institution=univ)
        dataset = Dataset()
        new_student = request.FILES['myfile']
        if not new_student.name.endswith('xlsx'):
            messages.info(request,'Wrong format')
            return render(request, 'upload.html')
        
        imported_data = dataset.load(new_student.read(), format='xlsx')
        for data in imported_data:
            value = Student(
                data[0],
                data[1],
                data[2],
                data[3],
                data[4],
                data[5],
            )
            value.save()
            
     
    return render(request, 'upload.html')
```

And I intialized it in **resources.py** as follow

`resources.py`:

```
class StudentResource(resources.ModelResource):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._institution=kwargs.pop('institution', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        print(self._institution)
   
    class Meta:
        model=Student
```

So, is there anyway I can set the value of **institution id** = **self._institution** so as to able to upload excel file that doesn't contain **institution id**????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right lines.  The way to do this is to pass the institution instance (or id) into the constructor, which is what you have already.  All you need to do is to set the `institution` instance onto the Student model instance before it is saved:

```py
class StudentResource(resources.ModelResource):
    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._institution=kwargs.pop('institution', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        print(self._institution)

    def before_save_instance(self, instance, using_transactions, dry_run):
        setattr(instance, "institution", self._institution)
   
    class Meta:
        model=Student
```

However, you are bypassing the `django-import-export` framework by calling `Student.save()` directly.  Don't do this.  Use the framework to handle instance creation for you ([docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#importing-data)):

```py
result = student_resource.import_data(imported_data, dry_run=True)
```

Comment: first, thank you for showing me right way! but still,..
        setattr(instance, 'institution', self._institution) ....
        print(self._institution), return None.    Even if, I set......... result = student_resource.import_data(imported_data, dry_run=True, institution=1) in views.py.... I hope you will show me what I haven't got right yet. thank you again for your help in advance

Comment: `student_resource.import_data(imported_data, dry_run=True, institution=1)` - this isn't correct, no need to pass institution here.  The best way forwards is to spend a couple of hours reading the documentation, and try out the example app.  This will give you a solid understanding of the library and save you a lot of time in the long run.